# Remesh modifier causes texture to go flat/disappear

Tags: texturing, modifiers, displacement

[image]

[image]

Hey Blender community,

I've been trying to add the remesh modifier to create even quads to allow for my textures to better displace. But when I add the modifier my textures become flat (See the image)

Is this a bug or is there a solution for this? I'm using the latest version of Blender and using the subdivision modifier is not a solution I'm looking for, I need those even quads (See the image)

When I remove the modifier or go into Edit mode, I can see my textures again. Would love to hear the solution.

Thanks!

Comment: The remesh modifier destroys UVs. You can try keeping another copy of the base mesh and adding a UV project modifier further down with the base object as origin